# Showing that $f(x)=x^2+2x+3$ is irreducible and primitive.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, primitive-roots

So I am given the following polynomial $f(x)=x^2+2x+3\in \mathbb{Z}_5[x]$ and asked to show that it is first irreducible and then that it is primitive.

So in terms of irreducibility, this is equivalent to saying that $f(x)$ has no roots in $\mathbb{Z}_5$, which is easy enough to check:

$f(0)=3\neq0,f(1)=1\neq0,f(2)=1\neq0,$

$f(3)=3\neq0,f(4)=2\neq0,f(5)=3\neq0$

Hence it is irreducible. Now my issue is showing that it is primitive.. I have seen some examples and attempted to follow them but feel as though I'm not really understanding the concepts.

We can deduce $|F^*|=5^2-1=24$ so, $o(\alpha)=24$. 
We know $24=3\times2^3$ and that $12,8$ are the proper maximal factors,so we just need to show that the following is true:

$\alpha^{12}\neq1$ and $\alpha^{8}\neq1$.

Now I'm not sure if any of this is right and I'm not sure, assuming it is correct, how to show the two equations above are actually true.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What definition of primitive are you using?

Comment: Note:  it is not true that irreducibility is "equivalent" to saying that $f(x)$ has no roots $\pmod 5$, unless you are working in the field of five elements which you do not specify.  $x^2+1$ has a root $\pmod 5$ but it is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: @FahadSperinck We use the following definition: For irreducible $p \in K[t]$, p is primitive in the sense that if $p|ab; (a,b\in K[t], deg(a)\geq1,deg(b)\geq1)$ then either $p|a$ or $p|b$.

Comment: @lulu My mistake! Perhaps equivalent is the wrong word, it's just my lecturer used the same method of working to show the same thing for a different polynomial so I assumed the equivlence. Is there some other reasoning behind why it is okay to just check the roots mod 5?

Comment: Well, first of all...what field are you working over?  I guessed $\mathbb Q$ but that was just a guess.  If that guess is correct, then it certainly suffices to show irreducibility $\pmod p$ for any single prime $p$.  After all, a factoring over $\mathbb Q$ would give a factoring over every finite field.  But "sufficient" is not the same as "equivalent".  Had you found a factoring $\pmod 5$ you could simply have tried other primes (though it is easy to see irreducibility over $\mathbb Q$ directly).

Comment: @lulu Apologies, we are working in $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$.

Comment: Do you know Eisenstein's criterion?

Comment: Ah, that should be added to the question.  I expect your readers all thought you meant $\mathbb Q$.  Note:  as you are working in the field of five elements what you said was correct.  Irreducibility is equivalent to the absence of roots $\pmod 5$ in this particular case.

Comment: @MarkBennet I don't think we have covered that, no

Comment: @lulu Yes my mistake! I thought I did include it, I shall edit the question now :)

Comment: To be clear:  Eisentstein has no bearing on this situation as you are working over a finite field.  It comes into play over $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: @lulu I didn't read anything about finite fields. One way of looking at this is as $(x+1)^2+2$

Comment: @MarkBennet  Yes, the first version of this question said nothing about the field of definition of this polynomial.  The OP has edited to make it clear that the field of interest is the field of five elements.

Comment: As to the question, I am more used to the definition of primitive which asks that the roots be primitive elements of the extension field.  As the extension field has order $25$ that is equivalent to showing that a root $\alpha$ of your quadratic has order $24$ which in turn is equivalent to showing that it does not have order $1,2,3,4,6,12$.  Is that something you have looked at?

Comment: Note:  it isn't clear to me that your definition is equivalent to the standard one.  All irreducibles have the property you require.

Comment: @lulu Yes! It is what you described, I am having issues finding a formal definition in the notes given but the method you have described is what I am expected to do. It is what I was aiming for with my working, however we just use the maximal proper factors as opposed to all factors

Comment: Ok, good.  So, let $\alpha$ be a root and then just compute $\alpha^n$ for $n\in \{2,3,4,6,12\}$.  In this case, all you really need is to see whether $\alpha^{12}$ is $1$ or $-1$ as all the proper factors divide $12$ though it is good practice to check each power.

Comment: As an example to get you started:  we know $\alpha^2=3\alpha +2$ from the definition.  It follows that $\alpha^3=3\alpha^2+2\alpha=3(3\alpha +2)+2\alpha=9\alpha +1+2\alpha=\alpha+1$, so $\alpha^3\neq 1$.

Comment: Thank you so so much, this has clarified alot for me! Apologies for the badly constructed question.

Comment: Oh, no problem at all.  Side note:  after you have solved the problem, you can post a solution yourself.  Good practice for writing up solutions and the site frowns on unanswered questions.  Ping me if/when you post a solution and I will review it.

Comment: @lulu I have posted an answer now, I did use $8$ and $12$ as my lecturer does require us to use all maximal factors in regards to his marking. Please do review when you get a chance! I am quite prone to simple errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution requires manipulation of our original equation $f(\alpha)=\alpha^2+2\alpha+3$.

First I will show that $\alpha^8 \neq 1$:

We can see directly $\alpha^2=3\alpha+2,$ and

$2\alpha=4\alpha^2+2\implies\alpha=\alpha^2+1$.

So, $\alpha^4=(3\alpha+2)^2=9\alpha^2+12\alpha+4=4\alpha^2+2\alpha+4$.
We can sub in our $\alpha^2$ and simplify as follows: 
$4(3\alpha+2)+2\alpha+4=12\alpha+8+2\alpha+4=4\alpha+2$

Now, $\alpha^8=(\alpha^4)^2=(4\alpha+2)^2=16\alpha^2+16\alpha+4=\alpha^2+\alpha+4=3\alpha+2+\alpha+4=4\alpha+1$.
Hence $\alpha^8 \neq1$.

Next, to show that $\alpha^{12}\neq1$:

$\alpha^{12}=\alpha^8\alpha^4=(4\alpha+2)(4\alpha+1)=16\alpha^2+12\alpha+2=\alpha^2+2\alpha+2=3\alpha+2+2\alpha+2=4$.
Hence we have also shown $\alpha^{12}\neq1$.

Therefore, we can conclude $f(x)$ is primitive.

Comment: Looks good (+1).  One small note:  often it is computationally easier to use negative representatives for the residues.  Thus, I'd be inclined to write $\alpha^4=2-\alpha$ to keep the coefficients small.  This is a lot more significant when you are manipulating numbers modulo large primes.

Comment: Ah okay I will keep that in mind for future questions. Thank you so much for all the help!